# How to convert psd to android xml file

Tags: android

How to convert psd image to xml code to reducing size of android application and work effectively and android xml design improve to application performance fast.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such conversion tool. XML is a vectorial format. You must use JPG or PNG.

Answer (score 3):

you can use these software for convert the psd to xml
http://www.psd2androidxml.com/

2nd is you can use the png file to drawable folder and use it

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to achieve this.

One way is to watch tutorials and learn how to do it by yourself.

The second way is to use some automated online tools, however they are not reliable, and you will have to correct the code manually.

The site that was mentioned by Nirav Shah, [www.psd2androidxml.com](http://www.psd2androidxml.com), is a service, not a software. You send the PSD files to them, and they hand code them according to your specifications. It may cost more than the previous two solutions, but the result is better compared to automated online tools.